# Unknown "property" in MongoDB connection

Tags: mongodb

I've this mongodb connection string:

```
mongodb://user:password@aaaprod01/sv01-mongod.gb.domain.com:27017,sv02-mongod.gb.domain.com:27017,sv03-mongod.gb.domain.com/ourdatabase?connect=replicaset;journal=true
```

The [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-formats) for replica set connection shows this template:

```
mongodb://myDBReader:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017,mongodb2.example.com:27017/admin?replicaSet=myRepl
```

I don't understand what is **aaaprod01** in my example. Is it the replica set name?

Comment: Maybe its in the name of the first mongod instance itself? Because it is usually mongodb://usename:password@instance1[:port],instance2[:port],instance3[:port]...../options...

Comment: `mongodb://userpassword@aaaprod01/sv01-mongod.gb.domain.com:27017` is an invalid URI. This should be `mongodb://userpassword@aaaprod01:sv01-mongod.gb.domain.com:27017` where `aaaprod01` is the password, and `userpassword` is the username. Where did you see this URI?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the colon between "user" and "password" (user:password). The URI was passed to me from a dba, without explanation. Ok, it can be the name of the mongo instance... I took out the aaaprod01 and we'll see if it works (we are going live in minutes!).  :-)